# When I launch an event, this call to the intent but not show in the client app

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have this event:
[Image of the intent](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sadxk59tve3h45b/dialogflow_01.png?dl=0)

And I have this code in the Fullfillment:

```js
  function LanzarEvento(session) {
    //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const uuid = require('uuid');
    const sessionId = uuid.v1();//user.uid;
    
    // Imports the Dialogflow library
    const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

    // Instantiates a sessison client
    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

    // The path to identify the agent that owns the created intent.
    const sessionPath = session;//sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
    console.log('sessionPath -> ' + sessionPath);
    let responseToUser = {
        'fulfillmentText': 'Voy a buscar los mejores alojamientos, dame unos segundos.'
    };
    sendResponse(responseToUser);

    // The text query request.
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            event: {
                name: 'PruebaEvento',
                parameters: jsonToStructProto({user_name: 'Andres',name: 'Andres'}),
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };

    sessionClient
    .detectIntent(request)
    .then(responses => {
        console.log('Detected intent');
        logQueryResult(sessionClient, responses[0].queryResult);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
  }
```

And this is the conversation in the Training section of Dialogflow:
[Trainning capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly8km868r5kyu5a/dialogflow_02.png?dl=0)

How you can see, the event was returning "Hola Andres", but this never appears in the Facebook Messenger or in the Slack.

Please, I need your help. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance,
Andrés Gilabert

Comment: Hi Andres, on your intent you have the tab Facebook Messenger on the Response section if I not mistaken you need to add a message content on that tab to send anything to Facebook, on your screenshots I can't see anything there, can you add a screenshot that shows that?